# Checking for root user in sh and bash

Tags: bash, freebsd, root, bourne-shell

I am attempting to write a script that automates the installation of ports/packages on new FreeBSD installs.  To do this, the user who executes the script must be root.

The system is "supposed" to be virgin meaning `bash` and `sudo` may or may not be installed; so I am trying to account for it.  To do this, I am checking if the user ID equals 0.

The problem is, between bash and sh, the environment variables are different:

- bash -> $EUID (all caps)
- sh -> $euid (all lower)

Is there a different way other than the environment variable to check for root user or should I just adjust the checking of the user based on environment?

Comment: `sh` on FreeBSD is the Almquist shell, not the Bourne shell.  And the `euid` shell variable that you describe is set by _neither_ the Almquist shell _nor_ the Bourne shell.  It is set by the TENEX C shell.  You will find it quite difficult to write a script that works on both the Almquist/Bourne Again/Korn/Z shells _and_ the C shell.

Comment: @JdeBP - I learned something new re: Almquist.  As for the the varialbes, I am on a virgin FreeBSD install right now (save for bash) and those are the env. variables that are set; bash has all uppers and sh has all lowers.  My goal is to write something that's compatible in sh and bash only.

Comment: You may think that you are running `sh`.  But by the presence of that variable you are _clearly not_.  The Almquist shell, as I said, does not set such a variable.  `root` _does not have_ the Almquist shell as its login shell, note.

Comment: *`sh` on FreeBSD is the Almquist shell* and *root does not have the Almquist shell as its login*.  These statements are contradictory.  Either root has the Almquist shell in FreeBSD and I'm running it or FreeBSD doesn't use the Almquist shell.  I am running FreeBSD and logged in as root using the ***default*** sh shell.

Comment: No, they are not contradictory at all.  `root` has the TENEX C shell as its login shell, and that does not contradict `sh` being the Almquist shell at all.  As I said, you think that you are running `sh`. But in fact that is not what you are doing, as the presence of a shell variable set by the TENEX C shell, `root`'s login shell, clearly tells us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would check the value of [`id -u`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html), which is specified to:

> Output only the effective user ID, using the format "%u\n".

Perhaps like this:

```
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]
then
  : root
else
  : not root
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can simply test for `$UID == 0` in both shells. Since the name `root` isn't the important part, and you can actually have a user named `root` with a non-zero UID, or a UID 0 account named something other than `root`, this might be a better way of checking that the script is running as a privileged user.

Comment: I probably didn't explain it correctly so I'll fix.  I'm already checking for a a user ID = 0.  The problem is one shell the env. variable is in all caps and the other environment is all lower.

Comment: Shell variables can have any value and can not be trusted. I could easily set `UID=0` in my personal shell init files, for example.  Use `id` instead.